# Range across different Word.run contexts using OfficeExtension.TrackedObjects class

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js

I am trying to use the OfficeExtension.TrackedObjects class to access a range across different contexts (documentation and similar questions set out below - although slightly outdated). The goal is to have a taskpane search list the results in the taskpane, then select the specific result in-text when clicking the listed result (using javascript).

Here is what I have:

```
var items = [];
function basicSearch() {
   Word.run(function (context) {
    const results = context.document.body.search("Online");
    results.load("length, text, items");
     return context.sync().then(function () {
      context.trackedObjects.add(results);
    for (let i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
      let x = results.items[i].text;
      createtable("TestList", i, x, x);
      items.push(results.items[i]);
    }
     });
    return context.sync();
   });
}

function createtable(id, x, y, z) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.type = "button";
  cell1.onclick = function () { selectrange(x) };
  cell2.type = "button";
  cell2.onclick = function () { selectrange(x) };
  cell3.type = "button";
  cell3.onclick = function () { selectrange(x) };
  cell1.innerHTML = x;
  cell2.innerHTML = y;
  cell3.innerHTML = z;
}


function selectrange(x) {
  results.load("text");
  results.items[x].select();
  results.context.sync();
}
```

Could someone show me where I have gone wrong, or provide a full working example of how to track and call an object (or collection of objects) for use?

Resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/officeextension.trackedobjects?view=common-js-preview&viewFallbackFrom=office-js
[How can a range be used across different Word.run contexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275482/how-can-a-range-be-used-across-different-word-run-contexts/)
[Word Online Add-In: Using objects across multiple contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609667/word-online-add-in-using-objects-across-multiple-contexts)
[Tracked Objects throwing errors in Word Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223919/tracked-objects-throwing-errors-in-word-online)
https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins
(Building Office Add-ins using Office.js has a working example, but it is in typescript and does not use trackedObjects - I have not been able to replicate it in my add-in).

When I run the above code, it says "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: results". I want it to select the specific search results displayed and pressed in the list. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I know which platform(word win32/ MAC/online) you run the code on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to define results as a global variable so that you can pass it to other functions. please reference the following code:

```
var results;
async function basicSearch() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    results = context.document.body.search("Online");
    results.track();
    await context.sync();
  });
}

async function selectrange() {
  await Word.run(results, async (context) => {
    results.load();
    await context.sync();
    results.items[0].select();
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

Comment: I have two follow up questions. Can this be used for other functions, such as "match"? Also, this seems to slow down my computer quite a bit, could you suggest if there is something wrong with my "untrack" function: 
    if (results.length > 0) {
    await Word.run(results, async (context) => {
      results.forEach((range) => range.untrack());
      results = [];

      await context.sync();
    });
  }